# What is the use of MS Office related lockbackreg.msi?

Tags: installation, updates, office-2003

I recently noticed that a installer file named lockbackreg.msi is included in a setup package that I use to install a large application on my machine. This file is said to be a MS .NET Update required by Office 2003 for addin functionality but I could not figure out the exact use of it.
Does anyone has any information on why this file is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's part of the KB908002 update package which also distributes extensibility.dll ( .msi ) and a couple other components.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908002

I don't know all of the details, but I do know this is a dependency of several assets in my software product line where I work.  These assets have to do with certain plugins / interop capabilities that we created for Excel, Powerpoint and Word for "pasting" to them and they won't work with out it.   This is a really large install that I create so I almost can't help wonder if you are using one of my installs.

I'd also look at all the "related" questions on SO.  The systems seems to be smart enough to answer the question for you.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried to search for answers using the name of this particular file but got no results